# How do I specify a constraint that says "collection of nullable types"?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, generic-collections, type-constraints

I'm trying to create a generic argument-validation method that checks collection parameters for null, empty, or **contains a null element**.

```
public void Foo(ICollection<MyType> bar)
{
    // Validate parameters
    ThrowIfNullEmptyOrContainsNull(bar, "bar");
                  .
                  .
                  .
```

If I only specify `ICollection<T>` in the type constraint, then `if (value.Contains(null))` generates an error, since `T` may not be a nullable type.

This was what I came up with, but it doesn't seem to be right:

```
internal static T1 ThrowIfNullEmptyOrContainsNull<T1, T2>(T1 value, string name)
    where T1 : ICollection<T2>
    where T2 : class
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(value, null))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);

    if (value.Count == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Empty collection not allowed", name);

    if (value.Contains(null))
        throw new ArgumentException("Collection contains one or more null elements", name);

    return value;
}
```

...but then I have to call the method with explicit argument types, something like this:

```
public void Foo(ICollection<MyType> bar)
{
    // Validate parameters
    ThrowIfNullEmptyOrContainsNull<(ICollection<MyType>, MyType>(bar, "bar");
                  .
                  .
                  .
```

Without explicitly specifying T1 and T2 in the call, I get an error "The type arguments ... cannot be inferred from the usage".

Can anyone shed light on how to do this?

Comment: I can't reconcile the title of your question with the body - can you try and clarify the task/problem a bit?

Comment: @usr No, he does need T1.  If he didn't have it then he'd be downcasting the value returned when calling this method.

Comment: Two possible different approaches that don't quite answer your question as asked: if your collections all implement the non-generic `ICollection`, you might use that instead, and forget about the constraint. It would simply never complain that any `ICollection<int>` contains `null`, which seems okay, since it never will. Other than that, you could overload your method, so that you have one method for reference types, and one different method (with the same name) for nullable value types.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it a little clearer. Basically, I'm trying to ensure that this method is called only for ICollection<nullable-type> (and not something like ICollection<int>).

The type constraint syntax is confusing me. Initially, I just had `where T : ICollection<T>`, but that allows non-nullable types like `int`.

Comment: You should not be editing your question to ask an entirely different question, particularly after the question that you asked has been answered.  If you want to know how to allow the generic type arguments to be inferred then that's an entirely different question from asking how to support nullable types, and it should be a separate question.

Comment: I edited to clarify, not to change the question.

Comment: @ScottSmith There is *no* generic parameter constraint that says "`T` must be nullable". `where T : class` means `T` must be a reference type, which disallows nullable value types such as `int?`. The only way to accept reference types, to also accept nullable value types, but to *not* accept non-nullable value types, is to separate the former two, to provide different overloads for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compare a non-nullable type with null, because all objects can be cast to `object` and hence compared:

```
bool obviouslyFalse = 1 == null;
```

This will result in a warning, but is valid. Obviously it's going to always be `false` and indeed the compiler will optimise by removing the comparison and giving us the equivalent as if we had `bool obviouslyFalse = false;`.

With generics the same applies in that with:

```
T item = getTFromSomewhere;
bool obviouslyFalseIfTIsntNullable = item == null;
```

Then this is valid for all possible `T`, and while the compiler can't remove the comparison, the jitter can, and indeed will.

Hence therefore we can have:

```
internal static TCol ThrowIfNullEmptyOrContainsNull<TCol, TEl>(TCol collection, string name)
    where TCol : ICollection<TEl>
{
  if (ReferenceEquals(value, null))
      throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
  if (value.Count == 0)
    throw new ArgumentException("Empty collection not allowed", name);
  foreach(var item in collection)
    if(item == null)
      throw new ArgumentException("Collection cannot contain null elements", name);
  return value;
}
```

This will work, but is wasteful if we've a large collection of non-nullable types; the jitter is not likely to remove that iteration, even if it does nothing, so it'll still get an enumerator and call `MoveNext()` on it until it returns false. We can help it:

```
internal static TCol ThrowIfNullEmptyOrContainsNull<TCol, TEl>(TCol collection, string name)
    where TCol : ICollection<TEl>
{
  if (ReferenceEquals(value, null))
      throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
  if (value.Count == 0)
    throw new ArgumentException("Empty collection not allowed", name);
  if(default(TEl) == null)
    foreach(var item in collection)
      if(item == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Collection cannot contain null elements", name);
  return value;
}
```

Because `default(TEl) == null` is always true for nullable types (including `Nullable<T>`) and always false for non-nullable types, the jitter will optimise by cutting out this comparison for all types, and removing the entire enumeration for non-nullable types. Hence a massive array of integers (for example) will be okayed by the method immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use `Contains`.  Iterate through the collection and compare the values to `null` explicitly:

```
internal static T1 ThrowIfNullEmptyOrContainsNull<T1, T2>(T1 value, string name)
    where T1 : ICollection<T2>
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(value, null))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);

    if (value.Count == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Empty collection not allowed", name);

    foreach (var item in value)
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Collection contains one or more null elements", name);

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

```
if (value.Any(item => item == null))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Collection contains one or more null elements", name);
}
```

As in:

```
internal static T1 ThrowIfNullEmptyOrContainsNull<T1, T2>(T1 value, string name)
    where T1 : ICollection<T2>
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(value, null)) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);

    if (value.Count == 0) 
        throw new ArgumentException("Empty collection not allowed", name);

    if (value.Any(item => item == null)) 
        throw new ArgumentException("Collection contains 1 or more null items", name);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: I think I'll still get a compile error since `value` is a collection of objects of type `T`, so `item` may not be a nullable type.

Comment: You're right, I don't get a compile error, but I do get a warning: "Possible compare of value type with 'null'". Thing is, I'm trying to _limit_ incoming argument so that it doesn't allow me to pass in a collection of value types.

Answer (score 1):

What about an extension method.   Wrap with exceptions or  messages as required

```
  public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this ICollection<T> alist) where T:class
    {
        if (alist == null || alist.Count == 0){
            return true;
        }
        if (alist.Any(t => t == null)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**use:**

```
 if ( myList.IsNullOrEmpty  ) {
   //.. exception, error handling
  }
```

No need to pass the type of MyList since MyList must implement ICollection
Might be useful for you no need to pass type requirement.
**Added T:Class to suggestion.**  But you knew about that already :-)

Comment: Hmmm, so could I do this?

`public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this ICollection<T> alist) where T : class {`

?

Comment: `int?` is a nullable type, but will be blocked by `class`.